# Android Parcelable class for savedInstanceState

Tags: android

in my application i'm trying to use Parcelable class to save savedInstanceState bundle, for this action i'm create this below code:

```
public class SaveInstanceState implements Parcelable {

    String  stringStates;
    Integer integerStates;
    boolean booleanStates;


    public SaveInstanceState(String str) {
        this.stringStates = str;
    }


    public SaveInstanceState(Integer value) {
        this.integerStates = value;
    }


    public SaveInstanceState(boolean value) {
        this.booleanStates = value;
    }


    public SaveInstanceState(String str, Integer ivalue, boolean bvalue) {
        this.stringStates = str;
        this.integerStates = ivalue;
        this.booleanStates = bvalue;
    }


    private SaveInstanceState(Parcel in) {
        stringStates = in.readString();
        integerStates = in.readInt();
        booleanStates = in.readByte() != 0;
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeString(stringStates);
        out.writeInt(integerStates);
        out.writeByte((byte) (booleanStates ? 1 : 0));
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SaveInstanceState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SaveInstanceState>() {

                                                                          @Override
                                                                          public SaveInstanceState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                                                                              return new SaveInstanceState(in);
                                                                          }


                                                                          @Override
                                                                          public SaveInstanceState[] newArray(int size) {
                                                                              return new SaveInstanceState[size];
                                                                          }
                                                                      };
}
```

in Activity i'm try to save into class by:

```
    private ArrayList<SaveInstanceState> InstanceStateList;
    public class ActivityMainView ... {
    if (savedInstanceState == null || !savedInstanceState.containsKey("ActivityMain")) {

        InstanceStateList = new ArrayList<SaveInstanceState>();
        InstanceStateList.add(new SaveInstanceState(mLastMenuItemSelected));
        InstanceStateList.add(new SaveInstanceState(mIsShowingExitDialogs));

    } else
        InstanceStateList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("ActivityMain");
    }
```

now for this blow function i can not get from `Parcable` class and restore `savedInstanceState` from it

```
public void RestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("ActivityMain");
}
```

whats my code problem?

Comment: Did you override onSaveInstanceState method on activity?

Comment: @Konrad Krakowiak  yes. but i dont know how to restore from class

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your problem. What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak save `onSaveInstanceState` into `parcable` class and restore from it.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is answer but in method` onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  if(savedInstanceState != null)` then you can get by method `InstanceStateList  = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("ActivityMain");`